# Why is my component rendering when useState is called with the same state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple functional component with a boolean state. And buttons to change the state.

It is initially set to `true` so when I press the true-button, it does NOT render.

But if I press the false-button, it re-renders AND if I press false-button AGAIN, it will re-render even though the state is already set to `false`..

Could someone explain why the component re-renders when the state changes to the exact same state? How to prevent it from re-rendering?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const TestHooks = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(true);
    console.log("rendering..", state);
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{state.toString()}</h1>

            <button onClick={() => setState(true)}>true</button>

            <button onClick={() => setState(false)}>false</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestHooks;
```

Comment: Can I ask why do you cast it to string?

Comment: it will not render "true"/"false" if i pass the state unstringified. i guess i dont need it if the state is a string or number. but a boolean didnt work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) :

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> **Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out.** That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
> calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

So your component will not re-render every time `setState` is called with the same state. It will re-render only 2 times and then bail out. That's just how react works and that should not be a concern except if you're doing some heavy calculations in the render method.

Comment: thank you! I noticed they just rerender twice, was unsure why it would rerender twice and not every time. maybe its not much of a concern, i dont know. im just playing around but it doesnt feel correct to re-render even twice ? would you want this behaviour in a production app? (unnecessary rerenderings)

Comment: Yeah, that's just how react works and that should not be a concern except if you're doing some heavy calculations in the render method. In that case you need to memoize the calculations https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the `state` value is already the same as the one you are trying to update it with. The fact is, `setState()` will re-render your component regardless, that's just what React does to ensure all changes (if any) are reflected in the UI.

If you want to avoid unnecessary re-renders, use an intermediary function to check if the state values are already equal before updating it.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const TestHooks = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(true);

    const updateState = (boolean) => {
       if(boolean !== state){
          setState(boolean)
       }
    }

    console.log("rendering..", state);
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{state.toString()}</h1>

            <button onClick={() => updateState(true)}>true</button>

            <button onClick={() => updateState(false)}>false</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestHooks;
```

Answer (score -1):

`render()` will be called whenever `setState()` is called. That is the reason why we have the concept of `PureComponent` in React. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent