# React component re-renders infinitely with the same boolean value state being set in a useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was experimenting on below code snippet to understand the behaviour of React `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Setting state foo to false ...");
    setFoo(false);
  }, [foo]);
```

With current implementation the effect should be fired upon `mount`, dependency change and `unmount`. since `foo` is being set to the same boolean value `false` all the time, I was expecting the hosting component should render for 2 times only, i.e. initial loading and when the state `foo` is changed from `true` to `false`.

But in fact what I observed is that an infinite re-render loop is created by this code.

[Stack overflow - 57850595](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850595/why-is-my-component-rendering-when-usestate-is-called-with-the-same-state) posted a similar case investigating why the same state triggered a re-render, which directed me to the [Bailing out from a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) mechanism of React. It says "React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out". Shouldn't that mean there will be at most 3 times of rendering for the code snippet I posted?

Comment: Can you post the entire component you're using to test this? I just dropped that snippet into an otherwise empty component and it rendered only twice.

Comment: @Ben Oh, yup, you are absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I was too careless on this. Was actually testing this with enzyme shallow rendering for which there was a mock created on the `useEffect` hook... should have been more careful by rendering it out in a browser or via storybooks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Ben in the first comment, the code snippet actually works as expected. It was a mistake of mine which led to submitting a question that contains a false-negative.