# Why dosen't render anymore when i setstate same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know it is not correct code. Also I know same value state doesn't render page. But I wonder why page render one more when i set same value. Here is code.

```
import './app.css';
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function App() {
  const useTest = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  const [test, setTest] = useState(!value);
  const setTest2 = useCallback(() => {
    setTest(prev => !prev);
  }, []);
  return [test, setTest2];
 }
 const onClick = () => {
   setBool(false);
 }
 console.log('test');
 const [bool, setBool] = useState(true);
 const [test, setTest2] = useTest(bool);
 return (
  <>
    <h1>{test ? 'True' : 'False'}</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>testButton</button>
  </>
 );
}

export default App;
```

init rendering console.log is true. Then second rendering Third rendering is false then over rendering doesn't work anymore. I expected that second rendering than rendering doesn't work. But third rendering work. I want to know this flow. Sorry My english is bad. so I think you can't understand easliy. But please help me. Thanks

Comment: your state variable declaration should not be inside the function call `const useTest = (value) => {` it won't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my component rendering when useState is called with the same state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850595/why-is-my-component-rendering-when-usestate-is-called-with-the-same-state)

Comment: From [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update): *If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.*

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html  You will find your answer here.